# Git: Switch between forks, and create pull-request back

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git project, which each user has it own fork.

I have cloned the original fork, and now I need to go to another fork, to make some code changes and then create a PR from my fork to the original.

I'm loosing how to switch between forks, for example:

I'm at `gitlab.aws.site.net:webapp/webapp.git` and I need to checkout to `gitlab.aws.site.net:pablo/webapp.git` is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a remote (say, `pablo`) in your `webapp/webapp` repo. Then create a new branch (say, `feature`) with `pablo/master`. Do code changes and finally push to your **webapp/webapp master** branch. Now, Create a new Pull request from your `webapp/webapp feature branch` to `pablo/webapp master branch`!

```
# go into `webapp/webapp` repo
$ git remote add pablo <url of pablo/webapp>

$ git fetch pablo
$ git checkout -b feature pablo/master   # checkout to a new branch 'feature' with 'pablo/master' history

# do changes/fix codes here

# merge webapp/webapp changes into pablo (optional)
$ git pull origin master      # now local/feature = webapp/master + pablo/master changes 

# add, commit & push to webapp/webapp 'feature' branch
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'message'
$ git push origin HEAD        # push to webapp/webapp feature branch
```

Comment: thanks a lot, just 1 more Question, when I'm in `pablo`, how can I merge with last changes in webapp?

Comment: When you are in `feature` branch you have only `pablo` codes. Now if you want to merge `webapp` changes then just `pull origin master`. I have edited my answer.